# Android - APP crashes when I call startActivity() with an impact intent

Tags: android, android-intent, crash

```html
<activity
  android:name=".Fisrt"
  android:label="@string/title_activity_first" >
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
  </intent-filter>
</activity>
<activity
  android:name=".Second"
  android:label="@string/title_activity_second" >
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="com.example.MusicTest.First"/>
    <category android:name="ANDROID.INTENT.CATEGORY.DEFAULT"/>
  </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

And in my First.java, the code is below.

```
public final static String MY_ACTION = "com.example.MusicTest.First";

public void change(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(First.MY_ACTION);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

The problem is everytime I call change(), the APP would crash. Any Input will be helpful. Thanks.

/*supplement*/
**The log is below:**

> 08-10 11:59:08.873  17509-17509/com.example.root.musictest W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41ffcd58)
>   08-10 11:59:08.873  17509-17509/com.example.root.musictest E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: com.example.root.musictest, PID: 17509
>       java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
>       at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3829)
>       at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4444)
>       at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18457)
>       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
>       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
>       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5034)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:807)
>       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:623)
>       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>       Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>       at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3824)
>       at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4444)
>       at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18457)
>       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
>       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
>       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5034)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:807)
>       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:623)
>       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>       Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=com.example.MusicTest.First }
>       at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1632)
>       at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1424)
>       at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3439)
>       at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3400)
>       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:820)
>       at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3642)
>       at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3610)
>       at com.example.root.musictest.First.change(First.java:46)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>       at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3824)
>       at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4444)
>       at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18457)
>       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
>       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
>       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5034)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:807)
>       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:623)
>       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=com.example.MusicTest.First }

Answer (score 0):

Change your manifest file to:

```
<activity
  android:name=".Fisrt"
  android:label="@string/title_activity_first" >
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
  </intent-filter>
</activity>
<activity
  android:name=".Second"
  android:label="@string/title_activity_second" >
</activity>
```

To start `Second` Activity, try the follow code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(First.this, Second.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Explicit intent works for me. However, I just want to test an implicit example. Can you tell me why the App crashes when I use an implicit intent?

Comment: @BP233 You need to post your log

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below code for setting the action.

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(First.MY_ACTION);
startActivity(intent);
```

Second activity will be launched after that.

And of course, you can also add

```
intent.addCategory("android.intent.category.DEFAULT");
```

for setting category which you set for Second activity in AndroidManifest.

Answer (score 0):

There is spelling mistake in manifest

```
<activity
  android:name=".Fisrt"
```

should be

```
android:name=".First"
```

because your MY_ACTION string is **First**

```
public final static String MY_ACTION = "com.example.MusicTest.First";
```